# How to compare two matrices to see if they are identical in R?

Tags: r, matrix

For example, I have two matrices and I wanna know if they are identical in each element.

```
mymatrix<-Matrix(rnorm(20),ncol=5)
mysvd<-svd(mymatrix) 
newmatrix<-mysvd$u %*% diag(mysvd$d) %*% t(mysvd$v)
```

I used the following ways to compare them:

```
identical(Matrix(newmatrix), mymatrix)
all.equal(Matrix(newmatrix), mymatrix)
```

Why the first one doesn't return TRUE?
No matter I use Matrix from the matrix package or the matrix from base package

Answer (score 14):

They are not exactly equal (per `identical`) because of very small differences:

```
> max(abs(Matrix(newmatrix) - mymatrix))
[1] 1.110223e-15
```

but these differences are smaller than the default `tolerance` inside `all.equal`:

```
> .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5
[1] 1.490116e-08
```

so `identical` will return `FALSE` and `all.equal` will return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
> dput(Matrix(newmatrix))
new("dgeMatrix"
    , x = c(-0.705193264426589, 0.68023073271425, 0.0726318059033283, -0.111055227906436, 
-0.113940777963113, 0.726463241417717, -0.343435098646076, 0.885225942372688, 
-0.549848405897803, -0.0227469387867766, -0.927524398860002, 
0.58047674424687, 0.521144348439824, 0.279602090928527, -1.31686400403363, 
0.906874499735628, -0.276997805548975, 0.632960950203858, 0.453881309098762, 
-0.00528540521655077)
    , Dim = 4:5
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)
    , factors = list()
)

> dput(newmatrix)
structure(c(-0.705193264426589, 0.68023073271425, 0.0726318059033283, 
-0.111055227906436, -0.113940777963113, 0.726463241417717, -0.343435098646076, 
0.885225942372688, -0.549848405897803, -0.0227469387867766, -0.927524398860002, 
0.58047674424687, 0.521144348439824, 0.279602090928527, -1.31686400403363, 
0.906874499735628, -0.276997805548975, 0.632960950203858, 0.453881309098762, 
-0.00528540521655077), .Dim = 4:5)
```

Clearly these are not the same data structures.

Answer (score 4):

The first one you are comparing:

```
> Matrix(newmatrix)
4 x 5 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  0.5052901 -0.3264201 -0.8576401 -0.62666359  2.1076090
[2,]  0.2356111  0.4911067 -1.2376674  1.11231840  0.8576557
[3,] -0.6244670  1.4423943 -1.2820541 -0.05297437 -2.0458810
[4,] -0.2669079  1.1218459  0.6371571 -0.52168139  0.2163623
```

with:

```
> mymatrix
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  0.5052901 -0.3264201 -0.8576401 -0.62666359  2.1076090
[2,]  0.2356111  0.4911067 -1.2376674  1.11231840  0.8576557
[3,] -0.6244670  1.4423943 -1.2820541 -0.05297437 -2.0458810
[4,] -0.2669079  1.1218459  0.6371571 -0.52168139  0.2163623
```

And if you read the help for `identical` you see: `The safe and reliable way to test two objects for being _exactly_ equal.` You are comparing a `Matrix`-class object with an R standard matrix object. They are very different. Even two object with different attributes won't be identical:

```
> x
a b c d 
1 2 3 4 
> y
[1] 1 2 3 4
> x==y
   a    b    c    d 
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
> identical(x,y)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether 2 matrices are same (identical) or not as follows.

Suppose you have 2 matrices, `newMatrix` and `oldMatrix`, which could be any dimension.

`which (which (newMatrix == oldMatrix) == FALSE)` will return `integer (0)` if the two matrices are identical.